# Trying to import a csv file, containing non-ascii characters, to a dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, import, ascii

When trying to import a csv file into a pandas dataframe I get a UnicodeEncodeError because some of the characters in the csv can't be encoded by ascii. The csv is orignally encoded in utf-8.

My code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'‪F:\data\Housing.csv')
```

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u202a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)*

Now I have tried some suggestions posted on stackoverflow to resolve this issue, but alas nothing has worked as of yet.

For instance, I saved the csv file as ascii encoded and tried using the open command hoping I could work my way to a dataframe from there:

```
open('‪F:\data\Housing.csv', mode='r', encoding='ascii', errors='replace')
```

However, whether I use 'replace' or 'ignore' the error still remains, I have also tried using the original encoding='utf-8':

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u202a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)*

I also tried using codecs.open, but the same result persists.

Perhaps someone here knows how one can solve this issue? Preferably I would replace the characters causing errors with a ? sign.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: I have tried this, but I get the same error

Comment: are you able to view the contents of the file in a text editor ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Check the encoding of your csv file. On unix, it can be done using `file -i *csv`

Comment: The file is encoded as utf-8. Sorry, it took me some time to check it.

Comment: This is UnicodeEncodeError, not UnicodeDecodeError.  It seems you are succeeded to *read* the csv file.  You may be failed to *display* it.
What is your environment?  Can `print("あ")` show あ?